# How to make a realistic network congestion?

Tags: simulator, traffic

How could make realistic congestion for the network in simulators typically? 
 Do i have to make congestion in network by playing with background traffic? for example by making an script; sending specific CBR background traffic from 10 seconds of simulation to 20 seconds then, FTP from 20 seconds to 30 seconds and so on?  Or is there any tool that follow Internet traffic model?

Beside the above question, Is there any model in NS3 that i can use for making network congestion? In another words, how could we have a realistic network congestion in NS3?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are appliances to address this from a test and measurement perspective. Some of them are sophisticated enough to model entire networks of impairment characteristics.